# How to Install GDAL with ECW Support on Windows

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system, ecw

What do I download from http://www.gisinternals.com/stable.php for Win7-32 to cut 1:1M map sheets out of Australia.ecw file in GDA94/Geographic and save them as geotiff in WGS84/Geographic? I would like to automate the process to cut all of the 1:1M map sheets then reproject and convert them to geotiffs.

(I am thinking gdalinfo, gdaltranslate, gdalwarp but I am not clear about the ecw support and don't understand the gisinternals release numbers.)

Comment: How to install GDAL with ECW support is a separate question (install GDAL core with msi installer ans ECW support with msi installer as well, you will understand the versions if you read and think a bit). For your task, read http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html and use -te and -te_srs. It may also need some reading, thinking, and experimenting but you will do it.

Comment: Yes, I've read the gdalwarp.html. How exactly does the ecw support work in the programs (eg gdalwarp)?

Comment: Specifically, as I see it the windows stable releases at gisinternals are outdated compared to the other platforms and bundled with crapware.

Comment: I use just the dev versions but tell me more which crapware and the download link you used.

Comment: http://download.gisinternals.com/sdk/downloads/release-1800-gdal-mapserver/gdal-201-1800-core.msi

Comment: This has V2: http://download.gisinternals.com/sdk/downloads/release-1800-gdal-mapserver/gdal-201-1800-core.msi. Why does it include the MapServer? I read of problems when different programs are using gdal.

Comment: First, if you install with core installer I don't believe that MapServer is installed despite the name of the download directory, Even if MapServer were installed it would mean only 10 additional exe files, total disk space used 90 kB so no need to worry.

Comment: If GDAL supports ECW you can see it in the list of supported formats. You can get the list with `gdalinfo --formats`. If ECW is supported you can use ECW files as input for GDAL programs for example `gdalwarp [options] input.ecw output.tif`. For writing ECW out you will need a license from Hexagon. Installer from gisinternals installs a read-only driver. Alternatively you can install a read/write driver which is using a very old (and rather buggy) ECW SDK version which allows also writing ECW if files are small enough.

Comment: Excellent detail. My problem was that I wasn't using an ECW version.

Comment: I changed the title to match most of the comments and answers. If you still need help on the extraction, please put it as a separate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to visit http://www.gisinternals.com/stable.php. Depending on the Microsoft VC runtime version (2005 to 2013) and win32 vs win64bit, you get a full package of GDAL. Following the `information` link on the site, you get to know which formats are supported.

If you don't need mapserver binares, just ignore them. The installer will not set up a full mapserver automatically.

Regarding ECW support, some versions (like http://www.gisinternals.com/packageinfo.php?file=release-1400-gdal-1-11-mapserver-6-4.zip) include SDK 3.3 support, which enables you to write ECW files up to a certain limit without the need for a license.

http://www.gisinternals.com/packageinfo.php?file=release-1700-gdal-1-11-mapserver-6-4.zip comes with support for SDK 5.1 (meaning read-only usage), while the MSVC13 compiled version has no ECW support at all.

So choose the package that fits your needs. All have the standard GDAL and OGR utilities.

Comment: Excellent answer. I don't really understand the subtly of the different Microsoft VC runtime version (2005 to 2013) and why different MSVC runtimes have different features. It seems inevitable that my collection of gdal versions (and clashes) will continue to grow. I realise that it is all documented but it is in that terse linux programmer style which doesn't always achieve communication.

Comment: See it as an offer: gisinternals compiles the same GDAL version with different choices on every MSVC compilation. The ECW SDK 3.3 and 5.1 can not be used together. I use the zip versions from gisinternals. They can live together without problems on the same computer. Once you start the SDK.bat, all environment variables are set to this version, until you close the DOS box.

Comment: An old blog [here](http://cartometric.com/blog/2011/10/17/install-gdal-on-windows/). The ecw component still needs to be installed.