# How to cut image into Map Sheets with GDAL?

Tags: gdal, clip

I want to divide a whole raster map image into map sheets.

The gdal tiling or clipping functionality doesn't seem to do it.

Comment: what did you try? what program, which arguments? what happened or didn't  happen?

Comment: All the GPS people use Global Mapper. I think it can be done with gdal but surely it is not limited to clipping single sheets.

Comment: you can edit your question to add more information to help people answer it

Comment: If I put too much in there people complain that it is a number of questions. My workflow is complicated. I need to cut sheets from an ecw file, reproject and save as geotiffs. What else can I say?

Comment: that is a start - as I said you need to tell us what you are trying to do and what you have already tried, and what is not working.

Comment: is this just a duplicate of your other question - https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/154929/how-to-reproject-part-of-ecw-file-in-gdal?

Comment: I'll post some same command lines tomorrow. Pretty ugly.

Comment: GDAL tools does not have a ready made tool for cutting by map sheets. Gdal_translate has a -projwin and gdal_warp has a -te parameter which can be used for clipping one area at a time. You must make a batch file or script which is feeding the extents of your mapsheets one by one into these parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single 1:1M map sheet can be reprojected and extracted with the following command:

gdalwarp -t_srs WGS84 -te 144 -36 150 -32 -crop_to_cutline 76943_Aus t_gda94.ecw AustTopo250_SI55.tif

This is dependent on an ecw driver being loaded.

Thanks to @user30184 for the tip:

> GDAL tools does not have a ready made tool for cutting by map sheets.
>   Gdal_translate has a -projwin and gdal_warp has a -te parameter which
>   can be used for clipping one area at a time. You must make a batch
>   file or script which is feeding the extents of your mapsheets one by
>   one into these parameters.

Comment: Good 2014 tutorial on this subject: http://www.geos.ed.ac.uk/~smudd/TopoTutorials/html/tutorial_raster_conversion.html