# Problems with .ecw files using gdalbuildvrt

Tags: gdalbuildvrt

I used

```
gdalbuildvrt C:\Users\Vector_district.vrt D:\177_SwissImage_10cm_2017_190410\2548\*.ecw
```

trying to create a vrt.
The console gives back following error for each file in the folder:

> ERROR 4:
>   `D:\177_SwissImage_10cm_2017_190410\2548\file.ecw'
>   not recognized as a supported file format. Warning 1: Can't open
>   D:\177_SwissImage_10cm_2017_190410\2548\file.ecw.
>   Skipping it

When I use an other folder with `.tif` files it works perfectly.

How do I have to adapt my code to create a vrt with `.ecw`-files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is likely that your version of GDAL was not installed with support for ECW files.

You can install a version that does by following the suggestions in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/154953/22166).

Comment: I tried to install the .ecw-plugin from the link in your mentioned answer. Somehow it didn't work. But now I updated my QGIS-version from 3.4 to 3.12 and it works.